# Computing normaliser of diagonal and triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

I would like to compute $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{d_n})$, $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{u_n})$ and $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{l_n})$, where $\mathfrak{d_n}, \mathfrak{u_n}, \mathfrak{l_n}$ are the Lie algebras of diagonal matrices, upper triangular matrices and lower triangular matrices respectively.

By definition, $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{d_n})= \left\{ x \in \mathfrak{gl}(n) : [x, D] \in \mathfrak{d_n}, \forall D \in \mathfrak{d_n} \right\}$. By linearity, every $x \in \mathfrak{gl_n}$ is a combination of elementary matrices of type $E_{ij}$, so it will be enough to examine $[E_{ij}, E_{kk}] = \delta_{jk}E_{ik} - \delta_{ki}E_{kj}$ which is a diagonal matrix every time $j=k=i$. So, I conclude that $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{d_n}) = \mathfrak{d_n}$. Is this correct?

As for $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{u_n})$, one can first notice that $x \in \mathfrak{gl}(n) \iff x= u +l$ with $u \in \mathfrak{u_n}$ and $l \in \mathfrak{l_n}$. So, $t \in \mathfrak{u_n}$, $[x,t] = [u,t] + [l,t]$. Obviously $[u, t] \in \mathfrak{u_n}$ but I am not sure what conditions are to be made on $l$ such that $[l,t] \in \mathfrak{u_n}$ as well. I guess my question is: when is the bracket of an upper triangular and lower triangular matrix equal to an upper triangular?

Comment: Quite generally, $A \subseteq B \implies N_C(A) \supseteq N_C(B)$ so you alreday have that $N_{\mathfrak{gl}(n)}(\mathfrak{u}(n)) \subseteq\mathfrak{d}_n$, and probably the other inclusion is easy / follows from stuff you already used.

Comment: To prove the other inclusion I computed $[E_{kk}, E_{ij}] = \delta_{ki} E_{kj} - \delta_{jk} E_{ik}$ where $i \leq j$ and obtained that in every case the bracket belongs indeed to $\mathfrak{u}_n$. Thank you